# Assembly.LoadFrom - using Evidence overload to verify strong name signature

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Is it possible to use the Assembly.LoadFrom overload with the Evidence parameter to ensure the assembly is strongly named? I want to be able to specify the assembly name, culture, version, and public key token. If any of this information does not match the assembly should fail to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way to do this.

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(<fully qualified type name>);
assemblyName.CodeBase = <path to assembly>

Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get an Assembly's public key after loading it - if it loads successfully and has a public key, then it's strong-named:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom (...);
byte[] pk = assembly.GetName().GetPublicKey();
```

Better still, check the assembly's public key and version info *before* loading it:

```
AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName ("myfile.exe");
byte[] publicKey = an.GetPublicKey();
CultureInfo culture = an.CultureInfo;
Version version = an.Version;
```

If GetPublicKey() returns a non-null value, and then the assembly successfully loads, it has a valid strong name.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way for breaking the strong-name verification for patching System.Windows.Forms.dll. If I'm using it, there's not much you can do about it. My trick requires full trust.

What I did was patch the dll, deploy the patched dll, ngen it, and patch the loader to pick up the patched ngen image instead of the original. What I could have done was clobber the stock ngened dll. (I actually tested this path and decided potentially breaking somebody else's software was a poor choice.)

I'm not saying this is a good idea to do. I'm saying that depending on verifying signatures from Assembly.Load is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you delay-signing perhaps? If so, this will only work on machines on which you disable strong-name verification (sn -Vr) for that assembly. Otherwise, what are you doing? Has the private key for .NET framework assemblies been leaked?

Comment: The key hasn't been leaked. The loader assumes the file it gets is the file it asked for.

Comment: @Joshua can you maybe explain in more detail how your trick works for educational purposes. ?

Comment: @GerriePretorius: Done.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [System.ReflectionAssemblyNameFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblynameflags) enumeration:

```
bool f_public_key = ((asm.GetName().Flags & AssemblyNameFlags.PublicKey) != 0);
```